# navigator.getBattery cannot be found

Tags: javascript, html, battery, batterylevel

I made a program that would list the battery level and charging into a div. My code is below. For some reason, when I run it, it tells me that `navigator.getBattery` is not a function. How can I fix this?

```
function batttick() {
  navigator.getBattery().then( a=>{
    let m = ""
    let c = ""
    m = battery.level * 100 + "%"
  
    if(a.charging) {
      m+=" ⚡";
      c = "green";
    }
    console.log(c, m);
    document.getElementById("batt").innerHTML = m;
    document.getElementById("batt").style.color = c;
    })
} 
batttick()
```

Comment: What kind of program is this? I do not get this error in a browser.

Comment: Inside the promise when you do 'a =>', the promise returns the object and you are assigning it to 'a', you never assign a 'battery' variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an issue where you were using a variable `a` but were referencing `battery`.  See my edits and working demo:

```js
function batttick() {
  navigator.getBattery().then(battery => {
    let m = ""
    let c = ""
    m = battery.level * 100 + "%"

    if (battery.charging) {
      m += " ⚡";
      c = "green";
    }
    console.log(c, m);
    document.getElementById("batt").innerHTML = m;
    document.getElementById("batt").style.color = c;
  })
}
batttick()
```

```html
<div id="batt"></div>
```

Comment: In Firefox this API is exclusive to chrome code, in unprivileged web content and when debugging extensions it is always either not there at all or defined as `undefined`. On the `about:` pages it seems to be available and working. In Ungoogled Chromium it returns full battery and charging even though that's not true, so it's probably not of any use there either.

Answer (score 5):

The error that you are getting is not coming up when running on Google Chrome (version 100).

It looks like a few browsers don't support `navigator.getBattery()`. See the [browser compatibility on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery#browser_compatibility), or see the table below.

| Browser | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| Chrome | ✅ (>38) |
| Edge | ✅ (>79) |
| Firefox | ❌ (43-52) |
| IE | ❌ (no support) |
| Opera | ✅ (>25) |
| Safari | ❌ (no support) |

<sup>Key: ✅ = Supported, ❌ = Not supported.</sup>

If you notice that the browser that you are using isn't supported, you should upgrade or switch it, run the code, and it should work then.

---

Also, another problem in your code is that you are trying to get `battery.level`, when `battery` doesn't exist. This will likely throw an error.

It looks like you want to use the returned `BatteryManager` object, in this case, `a`. So, to fix it, simply use the code below.

```js
const m = a.level * 100 + "%";
```

This is now getting the `level` property from the already-defined `a` variable. When you change your code to this, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One common cause of this specific error message is that many browsers block the battery API if the page is not running in a secure context (HTTPS).

Check the "Secure Context Required" row of the compatibility chart: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery#browser_compatibility

Since this is now the top google search result for this error message, it's worth noting, even though this question is marked as solved.