Alternative for navigator.getBattery() of battery api?
What should I use instead of navigator.getBattery(), as it is not working?
I am working on a chrome extension and with this what I want to do is -
function toggleBatterySaver(enable) {
  if (enable) {
      navigator.getBattery().then(battery => {
          if (battery.level < 0.2) {
              chrome.power.requestKeepAwake("system");
          }
      });
  } else {
      chrome.power.releaseKeepAwake();
  }
}

It is throwing an error:
navigator.getBattery() is not a function.

Did you check the discussions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78105247/18667225 ?

Yes, I did and that didn't help me. My code is correct to best of my knowledge and my chrome browser is also updated.

That's really odd. I just implemented a small chrome plugin (using chrome 131.0.6778.70) and it is able to access navigator.battery() and print out the current battery level. It seems, we need more debugging information from your side. I will post my minimal, (hopefully) reproducible example and would like to ask you to test it and share your observations.

You can try to start with a minimal chrome extension that uses navigator.battery():
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Battery Test</title></head>
<body><div id="bat">-</div></body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>

script.js:
navigator.getBattery().then(battery => {
  document.getElementById("bat").innerHTML = "Battery: " + battery.level;
});

manifest.json:
{
    "name": "Battery Test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Battery Test",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "Markus",
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Battery Test"
    }
}

Edit
In a service worker context the navigator object is of type WorkerNavigator that is missing the battery property among others. One way to get around this is to open an offscreen document.
manifest.json (set permission "offscreen"):
{
  "name": "Battery Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Battery Test",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action":{
    "default_title": "Battery Test"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["offscreen"]
}

background.js (create the offscreen document "offscree.html"):
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url: 'offscreen.html',
    reasons: ['BATTERY_STATUS'],
    justification: 'read battery status'
  });
});

offscreen.html (runs your script):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="script.js"></script>

script.js:
navigator.getBattery().then(battery => {
  console.log("Battery: " + battery.level);
});

If you need the battery status in the background process itself you can find features to send messages from the offscreen page to your worker and vice versa in the documention linked above.

The one you provided worked fine. I found the issue with mine one, but don't know why it is. The same piece of code works when that is in the script.js file which is directly related to the index.html, but gives the error of navigator.getBattery is not a function when it is in background.js, which is the file in  background service_worker of  manifest.json

Ah, interesting! So you are using a servive worker. Pease edit your question and share your manifest and other important information., so others can reproduce your issue!

Thanks for your help. I will edit the necessary changes in question.

@baranwalayush: I have added information on using an offscreen document in my answer. Does that help?

Yeah, I can use send messages features to communicate between the script.js and background.js for functionalities like the battery status. And of course, it helped. Because of that only I was able to debug the issue and get it working. Thanks, a lot.

@baranwalayush: Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful :-)
